# ADX Table specify UTC time in policy retention period

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, retention, adx

Is it possible to specify a UTC time when deleting data in a table in Azure Data Explorer?

For example:

My Table is constantly being ingested with an Event Hub.
I want my Table retention policy to only keep data from 00:15:00 UTC to 00:15:00 UTC of next day.

I tried this, but I'm not sure about it.

````
.alter table TableName policy retention 
```
 {
     "SoftDeletePeriod": "1.00:15:00",
     "Recoverability": "Enabled"
 }
```
````

I didn't find anything related to time in the Microsoft ADX documentation.

Answer (score 1):

data retention is based on a `timespan` value (e.g. `1.00:00:00` for 1 day) and not a `datetime` value (e.g. `2023-06-22 17:53:55`).

- Even then, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/retentionpolicy): *The deletion time is imprecise. The system guarantees that data won't be deleted before the limit is exceeded, but deletion isn't immediate following that point.*

if you wish to delete data at a certain time, you can do so explicitly using the appropriate control commands (manually, or using a simple script/application). see: [Delete data from Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/delete-data)

alternatively, you could set a [row-level-security policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/rowlevelsecuritypolicy) on the table, that will filter out any records that you don't want to be returned to anyone querying that table, while having the retention policy eventually dropping the data.